# The text, ntext, and image data > types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE > operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

email belongs to table booking and its defined as type "Text" in our Microsoft sql server

```
SELECT email, 
 COUNT(email) AS NumOccurrences
FROM Booking
GROUP BY email
HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1 )
```

after running the above query(trying to find duplicates emails in the booking)
I got the error message like this:

> The text, ntext, and image data
>   types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE
>   operator.

I am using Microsoft Sql

Comment: Why do you use `text` for emails? _"ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types"_ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx **You cannot group by `text`**: _"Columns of type text, ntext, and image cannot be used in group_by_expression"_ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks but its old and in production, unlikely we gona change it

Comment: @HamletHakobyan old very old, thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @shanyangqu: However, _old_ is not a valid sql-server version ;)

Comment: If it possible in your very old sql server use `varchar(MAX)` instead of `text`.

Comment: the reason I said old, is becasue without any change the first answer does the job, with a bit modification

Answer (score 77, accepted):

since you are using `SQL Server`, why not change the data type to `VARCHAR(100)`?

To work around this error without changing the datatype, the `TEXT or NTEXT` column needs to be converted to `VARCHAR or NVARCHAR` when used in either the `ORDER BY` clause or the `GROUP BY` clause of a `SELECT` statement. eg, *which is alittle bit messy*

```
SELECT  CAST(email AS NVARCHAR(100)) email, 
        COUNT(CAST(email AS NVARCHAR(100))) AS NumOccurrences
FROM    Booking
GROUP   BY CAST(email AS NVARCHAR(100))
HAVING  COUNT(CAST(email AS NVARCHAR(100))) > 1
```

- [SQL Server Error Messages - Msg 306](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-306.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the accepted answer because of an issue with my ORM. This answer is only a workaround for when the accepted answer won't work, and is only valid if you only have the column in group by because it is required so you can include the column in the select.

It casts the column inside of aggregate function, so that it is not required in the group by, and the error will not occur and the returned data should still be correct.

```
MIN(CAST(email AS NVARCHAR(4000))) as email
```

Ideally you'd find a way to avoid this hack, but this may be useful in some circumstances.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @not2qubit If I remember right, instead of `SELECT email, name FROM users GROUP BY name`, which is not allowed in SQL Server, select the email using  `SELECT MIN(CAST(email AS NVARCHAR(4000))) as email, name`