# Entity framework TEXT data group by

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I run this query

```
    var myList = (from p in db.Full
                  where ((p.date_reception > begin & p.date_reception < end ) &
                          p.mc_host.Contains(host) & p.mc_host_class.Contains(hostClass))
                  group p by p.msg into g
                  orderby g.Count() descending
                  select new StringIntType
                         {
                              str = g.Key,
                              nbr = g.Count()
                         }).Take(20).ToList();
```

I get this error:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Is there a way to fix that?

**Note:** The data type of the `msg` column is text in the DB.

Comment: Have you tried to find out why you are getting this error? There are many resources on it if you just google it

Comment: Yes the query works fine when i use another column which is varchar type instead of msg

Comment: @krilovich i've just solved it by casting data type in my database from text to varchar thank you ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [The text, ntext, and image data > types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE > operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979413/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-whe)

Comment: @drexdrex make that an answer and then accept so that it can be used by others. also please specify in your question that you've used `text` as the datatype

Answer (score 0):

I Just solved it by changing data type in the Database from text to varchar 
by using cast(msg as varchar(max))msg