# ASP.Net VB Database connection issue

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, dbconnection

I have the following code to connect to my small SQL database:

```
<% dbConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; 
Data Source=db597845552.db.1and1.com; 
Initial Catalog=db597845552; 
User ID=dbo597845552; 
Password=passwordxxd" %>
```

And the following to pull names out of the Database

```
<%

dbAD.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees ORDER BY firstName ASC", dbConnect)
dbAD.Fill(dbRS, "employees")
If dbRS.Tables("employees").Rows.Count > 0 Then
For Each employee As DataRow In dbRS.Tables("employees").Rows
    Response.Write("Employee: " & employee("firstName") & " " & employee("surName") & "<br />")
Next
End If

%>
```

However the page pulls a error message:

"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."

Can anyone help as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/14979456/3036342