# Is it possible to group by using some matching patterns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to group by based on the the  matching patterns?

From the query shown here, I am getting an error

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    <colname>,sum(<colname>)
FROM 
    #TempTable
GROUP BY 
    CASE
       WHEN 
          <colname> like  '%abc%' then 'abc'
          <colname> like  '%efg%' then 'efg'
    END
```

My expected result is:

```
abc    2
efg    4.
```

Comment: What is the type of `colname` ?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the quick reply.Looks like I got the answer.let me look more into this :)

```
SELECT  CAST(<colname> AS NVARCHAR(100)) <colname>, 
        COUNT(CAST(<colname> AS NVARCHAR(100))) AS NumOccurrences
FROM    <tablename>
GROUP   BY CAST(<colname> AS NVARCHAR(100))
HAVING  COUNT(CAST(<colname> AS NVARCHAR(100))) > 1
```

Ref: [The text, ntext, and image data > types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE > operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979413/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-whe/36673269#36673269)

Comment: how does this answer your question??

Answer (score -1):

This one works with ROLLUP

```
SELECT coalesce(CAST(<colname> AS NVARCHAR(100)),'GrantTotal') <colname>, 
        COUNT(CAST(<colname> AS NVARCHAR(100))) AS NumOccurrences
FROM    <tablename>
GROUP   BY CAST(<colname> AS NVARCHAR(100)) with ROLLUP
HAVING  COUNT(CAST(<colname> AS NVARCHAR(100))) > 1
```