# How to fix "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    account, ' ', message_type, 
    MAX(message_no) as max_message_no, message_text
FROM
    (SELECT 
         account, message_type, message_no, message_text
     FROM  
         messages m 
     INNER JOIN 
         receivables r ON m.account = r.aracct
     WHERE 
         m.account IN (SELECT r.aracct AS account 
                       FROM receivables r 
                       WHERE r.balance <> 0)
         AND m.message_type = 'N') t1
GROUP BY 
    t1.account, t1.message_type, t1.message_text
```

I keep getting the error message:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

I essentially want the max `message_no` from each account and I want it to show the `message_text`, but it won't allow it because it is a `text` data type.

Comment: duplicate of this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979413/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-whe

Comment: Stop using the `text`, `ntext` or `image` data types, since MS have been warning about their removal for over a decade?

Comment: Not my call, go talk to my boss. I have been saying that for years

Comment: Well, then just tell your boss that you cannot complete your query as long as the datatype stays `text` ....

Answer (score 6):

`TEXT`, `NTEXT` and `IMAGE` are deprecated and should be replaced by the corresponding types `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `VARBINARY(MAX)`. You might cast your `TEXT`-column with

```
CAST(t1.message_text AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Might be enough to do this once in your sub-select:

```
SELECT account, ' ', message_type, MAX(message_no) as max_message_no, message_text
FROM
(
SELECT account, message_type, message_no, CAST(message_text AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS message_text
    FROM messages m INNER JOIN receivables r ON m.account = r.aracct
        WHERE m.account IN (SELECT r.aracct AS account FROM receivables r WHERE r.balance <> 0)
        AND m.message_type = 'N'
) t1
GROUP BY t1.account, t1.message_type, t1.message_text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare Text,Image,data types..If you want to use them,Change them to Varchar or Nvarchar..

some Examples below

```
   create table #t
    (
    yy text
    )

    insert into #t
    select '1'


    --fails
    select * from #t 
    where yy='1'
    /****
    Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.**/

    --fails
    select yy from #t
    group by yy

    /****
    Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
    The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.
    ***/


    ---Workaround 
    --Try changing the datatypes involved to Varchar or Nvarchar
    select * from #t 
    where cast(yy as varchar(5))=1


    select cast(yy as varchar(10)) from #t 
    group by cast(yy as varchar(10))
```

**References:**
    [The text, ntext, and image data > types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE > operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979413/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-whe)

Comment: And btw:: It seems rather obvious to cast `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `NTEXT` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. I case of `NVARCHAR` you should set your literals with a leading `N'1'`...

Answer (score 0):

so the issue with your query is you are casting it in your main section as

```
SELECT account, ' ', message_type, MAX(message_no) as max_message_no, message_text
FROM
(
SELECT account, message_type, message_no, CAST(message_text AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS message_text
    FROM messages m INNER JOIN receivables r ON m.account = r.aracct
        WHERE m.account IN (SELECT r.aracct AS account FROM receivables r WHERE r.balance <> 0)
        AND m.message_type = 'N'
) t1
GROUP BY t1.account, t1.message_type, CAST(message_text AS VARCHAR)
```