# Very strange SQL Server behavior: automatically convert most varchar data types to text

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a new SQL Server database at:

jdbc:sqlserver://[host]:[port];databaseName=WSO2AM_STATS_DB

I used the DDL (very close to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wso2/product-apim/e745561c1948ffcd225fea8cffedd6b00fbd4f27/modules/distribution/resources/stat/sql/mssql.sql) to create all the tables necessary for app servers to work. The strange thing is, after a few minutes, sometimes 10 minutes, sometimes hours, in a random fashion, most of the columns designed in DDL as `varchar` data types, initially shown in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio or Squirrel SQL client as `varchar`, then turn to `text` data types automatically.

I am looking into this and trying to find out why, such as: are there some triggers that caused this strange behavior? This is holding our development/test as the errors like this are now all over in our app server log:

```
TID[-1234] AppID[publisher] [AM] [2016-09-14 16:47:52,765] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag} -   

org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException: ***Error occurred while querying from JDBC databaseThe text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.***
```

It took us some time to find out why the errors were thrown as our DDL has NO `text` data types for any of the columns, as you can tell from the SQL file mentioned above.

By the way, I ran the same DDL from either Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio or Squirrel SQL client, same behavior, so it's not tied to the tools we used.

Comment: Columns in sql server do not just change datatypes by themselves. There is something running that is doing this.

Comment: I am checking with our DBAs. I will be very surprised if they convert varchar to the very archaic text data types in a trigger or something like that

Comment: Seems strange but it absolutely is not happening from sql server.