# Group By same or similar string sql

Tags: sql-server, string, group-by, equals

**1)** Suppose i have a table like this:-

```
| id    |  color_code  |      fruit      |
|:------|--------------|----------------:|
| 1     |  000001      |      apple      |     
| 2     |  000001      |      apple      |    
| 3     |  000001      |      apple      |      
| 4     |  000002      |      lemon      |         
| 5     |  000002      |      lemon      |       
| 6     |  000003      |      grapes     |
| 7     |  000003      |      grapes     |
```

How can i **group by** the fruit column according to the color_code column in sql server?

like this i suppose:-

```
| id    |  color_code  |      fruit      |   group_concat(id)  |
|:------|--------------|-----------------|---------------------|
| 1     |  000001      |      apple      |        1,2,3        |
| 4     |  000002      |      lemon      |        2,5          |
| 6     |  000003      |      grapes     |        6,7          |
```

**2)** What if i have 3 tables (like shown below) which require join, how can i achieve this?

**series_no** table:

```
|   id  |  desc_seriesno  |
|:------|----------------:|
| 7040  |     AU1011      |
| 7041  |     AU1022      |
| 7042  |     AU1033      |
| 7043  |     AU1044      |
| 7044  |     AU1055      |
| 7045  |     AU1066      |
```

**brand** table:

```
|   id  |  desc_brand     |
|:------|----------------:|
| 1020  |     Audi        |
| 1021  |     Bentley     |
| 1022  |     Ford        |
| 1023  |     BMW         |
| 1024  |     Mazda       |
| 1025  |     Toyota      |
```

**car_info** table:

```
|   seriesno_id  |  brand_id  |  color  |
|:---------------|------------|--------:|
|     7040       |    1020    | white   |
|     7040       |    1020    | black   |
|     7040       |    1020    | pink    |
|     7041       |    1021    | yellow  |
|     7041       |    1021    | brown   |
|     7042       |    1022    | purple  |
|     7042       |    1022    | black   |
|     7042       |    1022    | green   |
|     7043       |    1023    | blue    |
|     7044       |    1024    | red     |
|     7045       |    1025    | maroon  |
|     7045       |    1025    | white   |
```

this is my current query with sql server 2014:-

```
SELECT SN.id AS seriesid, B.id AS brandid, B.desc_brand
FROM [db1].[dbo].[series_no] SN
  LEFT JOIN [db1].[dbo].[car_info] CI
  ON CI.seriesno_id = SN.id
  RIGHT JOIN [db1].[dbo].[brand] B
  ON B.id = CI.brand_id
GROUP BY SN.id, B.id
ORDER BY SN.id ASC
```

but unfortunately it gave me an error since i cannot group by similar string this way.

i want it to be like this:-

```
|  seriesid  |   brandid  |   desc_brand  | count |
|:-----------|------------|---------------|-------|
|    7040    |    1020    |     Audi      |   3   |
|    7041    |    1021    |     Bentley   |   2   |
|    7042    |    1022    |     Ford      |   3   |
|    7043    |    1023    |     BMW       |   1   |
|    7044    |    1024    |     Mazda     |   1   |
|    7045    |    1025    |     Toyota    |   2   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1 Fruit Color

Assuming the table name is FruitColor, you can get the desired output by the following query -

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id
    , color_code
    , fruit
    , group_concat_id = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR)
                               FROM FruitColor AS fci
                               WHERE fci.fruit = fc.fruit AND fci.color_code = fc.color_code
                               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM FruitColor AS fc
GROUP BY color_code, fruit
ORDER BY id;
```

- The MIN() selects the first id of the group.
- Since there is no default GROUP_CONCAT function like in MySql in SQL Server, you have to use the `STUFF` function and FOR XML PATH. To learn more about group concat you can visit this  link  https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation
- You can customize the WHERE clause to match only by color_code.

#### 2.  You can have several options for this -

Option (a): Show counts for series with brands

```
SELECT seriesno_id AS seriesid, ci.brand_id AS bandid, desc_brand, COUNT(*)    AS [count]
FROM db1.dbo.car_info AS ci
LEFT JOIN db1.dbo.brand AS b ON (b.id = ci.brand_id)
GROUP BY seriesno_id, ci.brand_id, desc_brand;
```

- Here you don't need to use the series table if you want to show counts for cars having brand(s).
- You may not need to use the RIGHT JOIN on the brand table because if brand table contains a record which
  is not in car_info table, then seriesno_id would be null.

Option (b): Show counts for all the series with or without a brand

```
SELECT sn.id AS seriesid, ci.brand_id AS bandid, desc_brand, COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM db1.dbo.series_no AS sn
LEFT JOIN db1.dbo.car_info AS ci ON (ci.seriesno_id = sn.id)
LEFT JOIN db1.dbo.brand AS b ON (b.id = ci.brand_id)
GROUP BY sn.id, ci.brand_id, desc_brand;
```

Option (c): The work around for selecting a column which is not in a GROUP BY

```
SELECT seriesno_id AS seriesid, ci.brand_id AS bandid, MAX(desc_brand) AS desc_brand, COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM db1.dbo.car_info AS ci
LEFT JOIN db1.dbo.brand AS b ON (b.id = ci.brand_id)
GROUP BY seriesno_id, ci.brand_id;
```

- Here, if we are certain that each brand contains only one desc_brand, we can use an aggregate on it.
  This is bcause applying aggregate only one value returns that value. I used MAX here.

Personally I would go with option (a) as it makes more sense.

#### Update on GROUP BY exception for desc_brand being NTEXT...

Cast desc_brand to NVARCHAR to avoid the exception.

```
 CAST(desc_brand AS NVARCHAR(200))
```

Also I highly recommend using VARCHAR / NVARCHAR instead of any TEXT, CHAR etc. because they usually occupy more memory.

Comment: what if i have 3 tables which require join? how can i apply this method? You can refer the question answered by me below.

Comment: I have added the answer for second. Let me know how it went.

Comment: it works! btw, i changed the 2nd question's answer a) as discussed in here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979413/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-whe) because my desc_brand declared as ntext which will give error "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator" if just run as it is.

Comment: I have updated the answer for the workaround for desc_brand. However, Casting may cause performance degradation therefore you should almost always VARCHAR or NVARCHAR in the column declaration.

Answer (score 0):

use below code ..

```
SELECT distinct
       m.color_code
     , m.fruit      
     , group_concat = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(10),md.id) 
          FROM dbo.tablename md
          WHERE m.fruit = md.fruit and m.color_code = md.color_code 
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.tablename  m
```

for second :

```
SELECT SN.id AS seriesid, B.id AS brandid, B.desc_brand ,count(*)
FROM [db1].[dbo].[series_no] SN
  LEFT JOIN [db1].[dbo].[car_info] CI
  ON CI.seriesno_id = SN.id
  RIGHT JOIN [db1].[dbo].[brand] B
  ON B.id = CI.brand_id
GROUP BY SN.id, B.id ,B.desc_brand
ORDER BY 4 ASC
```

Comment: how can i achieve this if have multiple tables to join? Refer question below in answer section post by me.

Comment: can you suggest any references that i can look into? @sandeep rawat, btw i just edit back my post, can you help me with that?

Comment: but in reality both are different issue you should not  try to mix questions which are not related at all by doing  this question become relative reference for users (who were looking for same issue ).

Comment: Okay noted! My bad. Still trying to work around with stack overflow.
Btw, thanks for the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer

Comment: It's not working. Is it because of desc_brand column is string/varchar?

Comment: It returns error saying : "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator"

Comment: @user3657273 check now.

Comment: I already found where the problem is. The reason why this problem arises "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator." because my desc_brand declared as ntext. So i changed the queries as discussed here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979413/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-whe)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
id = SUBSTRING(group_concat,1,1),
color_code,
fruit,
group_concat
FROM(
SELECT distinct
   m.color_code, 
   m.fruit,       
   group_concat = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(10),md.id) 
                         FROM [Test_1].[dbo].[Stuff] md
                         WHERE m.fruit = md.fruit 
                            AND m.color_code = md.color_code 
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM [Test_1].[dbo].[Stuff] m)x
```