# Not sure what is causing sql error 306

Tags: sql-server

I originally had the following query on sql:

```
SELECT PROJECT_TYPE.PROJECT_TYPE_NAME, PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME, STATUS_TYPE.STATUS_TYPE_NAME,
COUNT(*) AS Tasks
FROM TASK
INNER JOIN PROJECT ON PROJECT.PROJECT_ID = TASK.PROJECT_ID
AND PROJECT.POURCENTAGE < 100               /* the following ANDs filters out inactive projects */
AND PROJECT.PROJECT_TYPE < 6
AND PROJECT.PROJECT_STATUS_ID < 3
INNER JOIN PROJECT_TYPE ON PROJECT.PROJECT_TYPE = PROJECT_TYPE.PROJECT_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN STATUS_TYPE ON TASK.STATUS_TYPE_ID = STATUS_TYPE.STATUS_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN PRIORITY_TYPE ON TASK.PRIORITY_TYPE_ID = PRIORITY_TYPE.PRIORITY_TYPE_ID
AND NOT PRIORITY_TYPE.PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME = 'Hold'                           
AND STATUS_TYPE.STATUS_TYPE_NAME IN ('To do','In Progress', 'To Verify')        /* only include projects in these 3 statuses */
GROUP BY PROJECT_TYPE.PROJECT_TYPE_NAME, PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME, STATUS_TYPE.STATUS_TYPE_NAME
order by 2, case status_type_name   /* orders by status */
  when 'To do' then 1
  when 'In Progress' then 2
  when 'To Verify' then 3
  else 4
  end
```

which correctly displayed the count of tasks in a certain status as [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TmQN.png). However, I wanted to replace the

> project.project_name

table with the shorter description listed in another table called

> project.project_desc

, which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y65Uj.png). I attempted to implement this by replacing all project.project_name's with project.project_desc, and adding

```
AND PROJECT.PROJECT_DESC IS NOT NULL
```

under the first inner join. However, this results in the following error

> SQL Error (306): The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be
>   compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

I'm not sure what's wrong with this now, all of the null values should be filtered out so i'm confused on why the query doesn't run the same way as it did before, just reading a different table instead. I do not have access to edit the database, so these changes must be implemented through the query.

Comment: update your question and add  your tables schema   .. need  to know the columns data type .

Comment: That's not a MySQL error, it's SQL-Server. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979413/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-whe

Comment: sorry, project_name is nvarchar and project_desc is ntext.

Comment: @user8093091 You need to change `project_desc` to `VARCHAR` if you want to be able to do this comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The text, ntext, and image data > types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE > operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979413/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-whe)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I find this easier to read...

```
SELECT pt.project_type_name
     , p.project_name
     , st.status_type_name
     , COUNT(*) tasks
  FROM task t
  JOIN project p  
    ON p.project_id = t.project_id
  JOIN project_type pt
    ON pt.project_type_id = p.project_type 
  JOIN status_type st
    ON st.status_type_id = t.status_type_id 
  JOIN priority_type xt
    ON xt.priority_type_id = task.priority_type_id 
 WHERE p.pourcentage < 100               
   AND p.project_type < 6
   AND p.project_status_id < 3
   AND xt.priority_type_name != 'hold'                           
   AND st.status_type_name IN('to do','in progress', 'to verify')  
 GROUP 
    BY pt.project_type_name
     , p.project_name
     , st.status_type_name
 ORDER 
    BY p.project_name
     , FIELD(status_type_name,'to do','in progress','to verify')
```

Comment: I've never liked that comma style, and putting `BY` on the line after `GROUP` and `ORDER` seems perverse. But does this really answer the question?

Comment: @Barmar Next time, I'll be sure to use the comments mark up window - but at the time of answering, I understood this to be MySQL. I guess the above doesn't really make sense in the present context.