# MSSQL 2000 database error while using GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

When trying to run the following query to pull the first instance of the number column:

```
SELECT number, comment
FROM workitem
WHERE (NOT (status_lookup_id IN (400, 600))) 
  AND (modified_on < DATEADD(dd, - 5, GETDATE())) 
  AND (due_on < GETDATE())
GROUP BY number, comment
```

I get the following error:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

I understand why the error is being thrown, I think, but I would need that information from the comments column. Is there some other way to get this data?

Comment: which column of your table has a datatype: 'nvarchar' OR 'text'?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Please provide table structure. Impossible to solve problem without it.

Comment: Sql Server 2000 is end of life, and has been for some time. It no longer receives any update... **not even critical security patches**.  Continuing to use it is dangerous and irresponsible, and moving to a supported system should be job #1.

Comment: In an ideal world, I am sure they would love to move to a new version of the software. Unfortunately, the overlaying software can only run on SQL2000. Having said that it resides in a secure environment with no access to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

you can cast & then use like below:

```
SELECT     cast(number as varchar(max)), cast(comment as varchar(max))
FROM         workitem
WHERE     (NOT (status_lookup_id IN (400, 600))) AND (modified_on < 
DATEADD(dd, - 5, GETDATE())) AND (due_on < GETDATE())
GROUP BY cast(number as varchar(max)), cast(comment as varchar(max))
```

It will truncate comment & number if its more then allowed char

Comment: Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Line 5: Incorrect syntax near 'max'.  Is this because its a SQL 200 db?

Comment: @GMR yes. And that is why you should always identify the version and edition of sql server you are using. And very few people are using such an old version at this point in time - which is a big warning for you and your organization. Back to the question - do you REALLY need to use a group by clause at all?

Comment: @SMor My apologies for that, however, these are the cards I have been dealt. Not sure whether or not I need a GROUP by clause. The "number" column does not contain unique values and I am trying to only pull the first record that contains any given number. Are there alternatives to cast in SQL 2000?

Answer (score 1):

It's not because of Group By, but the **datatype** of the column you are trying to Group by.

```
SELECT number, comment
FROM workitem
WHERE (NOT (status_lookup_id IN (400, 600))) 
    AND (modified_on < DATEADD(dd,-5, GETDATE())) AND (due_on < GETDATE())
GROUP BY cast(number as varchar(max)), cast(comment as varchar(max))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is MSSQL 2000 and it is throwing an error when I try to use cast.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, it seems to be your data types that are wrong? You didn't post them so I'm just assuming.

Try using this fix -> [The text, ntext, and image data > types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE > operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979413/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-whe)